# Programmatically added a shortcut to the All Users desktop and can't remove it

Tags: vb.net, shell, batch-file, registry, wsh

In VB.NET I used wscript.shell to add a shortcut to the desktop.  I didn't realize it created the shortcut on the "All Users" desktop, which means I can't delete it.  I don't have admin rights as this is my work computer, and asking for admin isn't an option.  WScript.Shell has a createshortcut method but not a remove shortcut method! I've been googling for days with no luck. Windows XP Pro 2002, SP3.

It may be impossible, but it's frustrating I can add a shortcut but not remove it.  If anyone could help I'd be so grateful!

Comment: You don't need a `DeleteShortcut` method because deleting a shortcut is the same as deleting any other file. Look for something called `Delete` or `DeleteFile`.

Comment: Nope. Cant delete it using a straight forward approach like a filesystemobject delete method.

Comment: I assume from your comment that you've already *tried* that? Then the problem must be permissions. Your administrator must have changed your access privileges between the time that you created the shortcut and now. There's no special trick here—if you don't have the necessary privileges, you can't delete the file. Sorry, there's not much else we can suggest.

Comment: No, it's a one way street permission.  The permission to add a shortcut is allowed, the permission to remove a shortcut is denied.  Annoying.  There really is no solution without getting admin rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add shortcuts to "All Users" through VB.NET then your work security obviously isn't up to scratch.  Let them know that the only reason it got there in the first place is because of their systems' lack of security, and that it needs deleted one way or another.

Is it really impossible to get an admin to delete it for you?

Comment: Sorry can't discuss on a public forum, but I really can't have an admin delete it for me.